# How to install TestNG in Visual studio code

Tags: selenium

Can someone please suggest me how to install testng in visual studio code?

Things i have done so far : 
1. Added below xml in POM

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: install *Katalium* extension to used selenium and testng in VS code

Comment: Installed Katalium extension . Am i supposed to add all my code into a new project ? How do i start using testng with this now ? Can you please help. i am new to this

Answer (score 1):

@Sowjanya H M try adding the Java Test Runner extension. it supports running both junit and testng tests. If you have your pom setup correctly, you can execute all tests in your project by selecting your pom.xml and in the command dropdown selecting `Run Code`. I have a later version of testng in my pom dependencies section:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

then in your build section, you should have configuration plugins for maven-surefire and your testng xml files. something like:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory> #not required
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- testng xml files for test execution -->
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>resources/sample.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```